# Can i install microsoft sql server 2012 system CLR types on windows XP SP3?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, smo

I want to install SharedManagementObjects for SQL server 2012 express on a windows xp sp3 machine that has SQL Server 2008 R2 Express edition but does not have any edition of SQL Server 2012.

But one of the prerequisites for installing "SharedManagementObjects for SQL server 2012" is that  microsoft sql server 2012 system CLR types must be installed.

I see i can download the SQLSysClrTypes.msi i need from [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065)

but am not certain it will successfully install on a windows XP SP3 machine that has .NET 4.0 and Windows installer 4.5 but no SQL Server 2012.

**EDIT:**
Same problem as this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/6bcde08f-e848-40a0-bc1f-e2f803a125da

I want to do this because i have an application whose backend database can either be SQL Server 2008 R2(for clients running windows XP SP3) or SQL Sever 2012(for clients on Windows Vista and above).

This application uses SMO for doing programmatic backup and restore operations.

Now in my application when i reference SMO for SQL Server 2008 R2, backup and restore fails on systems that have SQL server 2012.

If in my application i reference SMO for SQL Server 2012, backup and restore fails on systems that have SQL server 2008 R2 (i.e XP3 clients).

What is the common best way of handling such a requirement? Or what alternatives do i have?

All i need is for the WinForms application to support both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2012 and their corresponding versions of SMO.

Comment: This seems like the sort of question that could be answered by *reading* the system requirements (as per marc's answer), or just *attempting* the installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **System Requirements** section on that download page is pretty clear:

> ***System requirements***
>
> *Supported operating systems: Windows 7, Windows
>   Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2, Windows Vista
>   Service Pack 2*

There's no mention of Windows XP SP3 - so **no**, you cannot install this SMO library on Windows XP SP3. Time to upgrade.

Comment: since its No, looking at my requirements in the post's Edit section, what alternatives do i have?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior: you could create two distinct version of the application - one for SQL Server 2008R2, the other for 2012. Or: you could try to load the relevant assemblies dynamically, from disk, into a separate app domains. But the point remains: on Windows XP SP3, you won't be able to use the SMO 2012 assemblies.

Comment: @marc_2: do you think Embedding SMO dlls in Setup file will be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

I´ve an app that uses ReportViewer 2012. It needs SQLSysClrTypes 2012. I´ve tried to install it on XP but it says it needs .Net Framework 2, 3.5 or 4. Framework .Net 4 was installed but it doesn´t detect it, so I´ve installed .Net v2 and could successfully installed the SQLSysClrTypes.

Don´t know if this applies for SMO, but the CLR Types 2012 could be installed in XP.